# Untyped Higher Category Theory

Tags: higher-category-theory, foundations, ct.category-theory

I am currently trying to wade through the vast lake of higher category theory, a formidable task,or so it seems.

In the process, it has occurred to me that there is a basic analogy in place with various forms of type theories, typed logic, typed set theory, typed lambda calculus, etc.

In higher cats, one has 1-morphisms, 2-morphisms, and so on.

A fairly hierarchical structure, a ladder to infinity of sorts.

Now, whenever there are types, there is (almost) invariably an un-typed variant of the theory, which "forgets" the types. So I wonder if there is something along these lines already somewhere in the categorical endeavor.

> I try to be a bit more precise:
> imagine you are staring at a
> N-category (let us stick to a strict
> one, just for sake of simplicity),
> from the top, and you forget all the
> type labels. You see a fairly
> complicated diagram of maps whose
> endpoints are other maps, and so on
> and so forth. Now try to axiomatize
> such a structure. That would be an
> **untyped higher category** (**UHC**).
>
> Is there a reference for this structure? Now get rid of the strictness, and re-do the experiment. What kind of untyped higher categories are the result of stripping types from general higher cats?
>
> In the example I mentioned, the UHC is
> well-founded, in the sense that there
> are some fellows (the ground objects) who
> only point to themselves (I identify here the objects with their identity maps). Now,
> eliminate this distinguished role of
> objects and you will have a **not well
> founded UHC.**
>
> Is there a study of
> not-well-founded categories, in a
> similar spirit as there is a theory of
> not well-founded sets?

Comment: I don't really understand the question, could you make precise what for example untyped category theory (not higher!) would be about? 

Comment: @MircoMannucci If what you're interested is just an higher category in which there's only one object then I think you're looking for higher monoidal categories.

Comment: By object above I mean a $0$-morphism/cell of the higher category.

Comment: @Martin: I think Mirco is alluding to the difference between "untyped" set theory such as ZFC and ramified type theories such as Russell's theory of types where sets have a numeral "type" indicating their level in the hierarchy of the universe.

Comment: @Martin yes Lin is correct, I was thinking of ZFC (untyped) versus Russell, or Quine's new foundations. As for the specific question: think (I am being terribly sloppy here!) of object as 0-types, ordinary morphisms as 1-types. The untyped version of ordinary category theory would be a theory which obliterates entirely the distinction between objects and morphisms. Now, that happens already (see for instance Freyd-Scedrov's book), objects are "un-necessary", they can be identified with the identity maps. However, even here objects are not full-fledge morphisms, you can never apply an object 

Comment: to a map. So, the untyped category theory would go beyond that limitation. In fact, your question is very good: first things first! We should begin to axiomatise untyped ordinary category theory, and then move on to untype the entire chain. 

Comment: Hm, I don't think that an untyped category theory is interesting. Let's stay with usual $1$-categories. You don't want to compose arbitrary morphisms, but only those whose domain / codomain match. In order to formulate that, we need objects. And if you really want to compose arbitrary morphisms, you will just get a monoid.

Comment: Martin, incorrect. A monoid is a structure where EACH element operates on anything else. My still-to-be-born untyped category is something quite different: here each element f is still a "function", so it can operate  on another fellow, say g, ONLY if dom(f) =g. Quite simply, g is another "function", so it has its own dom(g) on which it can operate. 

Comment: Have a look at *Categories, Allegories* by Freyd and Scedrov - http://books.google.com/books/about/Categories_Allegories.html?id=fCSJRegkKdoC Allegories are probably close to what you're envisioning but note that the end result is not that different from categories - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_%28category_theory%29

Comment: @Francois perhaps you skipped the previous comments, I quoted exactly this book in my reply to Martin. Yes, it is relevant, but not for allegories: Freyd introduces categories talking only of maps (objects are identified with their identity maps), so it is in line with this approach (what I seek though is a bit more general, I want domains and codomains of maps to be arbitrary maps, not just identities). As for allegories, they are just an abstraction of the category of sets and relations between them. After all, they are yet another kind of ordinary category, so not relevant here. 

Comment: There is of course a (strict) $\omega$-category version of the single-sorted definition of a category (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/single-sorted+definition+of+a+category).  You have to be a little careful with it if you want $\omega$-categories rather than $(\omega+1)$-categories, but it works just fine.  You can find the $(\omega+1)$-version in Street's paper "The algebra of oriented simplices."

Comment: Mirco (taking a step back from Mike's comment) - there are two different things one can mean by untyped definition of a category. One is in the sense of Russel-Whitehead types, the other is in the sense of dependent type theory. Category theory is usually presented in some variant of the latter (e.g. Hom(a,b) is a type of arrows, dependent on a and b which are of the type of objects), but can be presented, as Mike hints, in a single _sorted_ definition, with just arrows being mentioned. Likewise one can define strict n-categories in a single sorted way without too much agony. Weak n-categories

Comment: should be possible to define in a single sorted way, in principle, but oo-categories are trickier. This is all very different to a RW-types approach. When you say "think (I am being terribly sloppy here!) of object as 0-types, ordinary morphisms as 1-types" I encourage you to not be sloppy and figure out what this means for 1- or 2-categories. This would help frame the discussion for higher categories, and how to think of them using RW type theory.

Comment: David, your prompt to be less sloppy is quite healthy. Indeed, it seems that my question was far from clear, and that has to be rectified. So: my main point is that, in the usual presentations of category theory, and of its higher order  versions, one generally chooses the option of describing it in terms of C_0 (the objects), C_1 (the morphisms), C_2 (the 2-morphisms) etc. Now, what I am after is basically a presentation of a category where there is ONLY one sort of objects, namely morphisms. Everything is a morphism, and there is no pre-defined types of morphisms. What there is, in my scheme

Comment: is simply the Dom(), Codom(), which associate to morphisms other morphisms, their domain and codomain (of course, in this theory, composition is available, in the usual fashion). Some morphisms, if one wishes to have a ground (ie the equivalent of objects), are such that Dom(m) =Codom(m). We could call those morphisms auto-referential, or simply objects. Now, equality. A simplified version of the theory would have only rigid equality between morphisms, whereas a looser one could also have distinguished set of morphisms, the equivalences. In fact, as a second thought, one could even be bolder 

Comment: and replace every notion of equality with suitable equivalences. Also, one could  allow for situations in which there are no ground objects in the sense I mentioned above, making room for some unfounded scenario where you start from a morphism, you get two other morphisms, its cod and dom, and repeat the process on both sides with no end. 
I hope I have  made a bit clearer what I am after: a "category theory" with nothing but one single type, morphisms. 

Comment: @Mirco, it sounds to me like the single-sorted definition is exactly what you want.  Have you looked at it?  (The "objects", though, are not just the morphisms such that Dom(m) = Cod(m), but those that are partial identities for composition.  Most categories have plenty of endomorphisms that are not identities.)

Comment: @Mike, yes, I finally looked into your ref and yes, that is what I want. Although this takes care only of the well-founded case (ie the ordinary categories, either 1-dimensional or higher-dimensional). I guess to handle the unfounded case one can simply drop the idempotency  thereby eliminating "objects". Now, that intrigues me more: is there any systematic study of un-founded categories? The reason I am asking is that, just like there are not-well founded set-theories, I see a potential usage of not well founded categories, both for foundational purposes and for math/computer science ones. 

Comment: The (vague) intuition I have about not well founded cats is that they are some kind of cats for which the ladder (in the typed perspective) is modeled after Z, instead of N: you can go up to the stars and down to the abyss, from any level. 

Comment: Hi Mirco, are you referring to what people sometimes call the "n-arrows-only" approach to n-categories? So for a small 1-category you have a set with a partial monoid structure on it so that objects and 1-arrows are viewed on the same footing....roughly speaking it seems that higher categories consist of n commuting partial monoid structures in which lower dimensions come from source maps and so on.

Comment: Reading through again, the above does seem to be what you are referring to.... for example a small double category is a set with two commuting partial monoid structures (where the identities are provided by the source/target maps) (in other words all the multiplication, source and target maps are all partial monoid homomorphisms in the sense that they preserve sources and targets). A 2-category is ditto but with one more condition that ensures that the "units" in one direction are units in the other direction. Then one can check if it makes sense replace "double" with n-fold and "2" with n....

Answer (score 4):

Hi Mirco, I'm putting my comment as an answer in case otherwise you don't find it. I wonder if you need the "n-arrows-only" approach.... where language of partial monoids replace categories. For example where objects and 1-arrows are treated on the same footing as 2-arrows in a double or 2-category in which the identities are provided by the source and target maps. Proposition: A small double category is precisely a set with two commuting partial monoid structures. (And a 2-category similarly but with an extra condition.) Would it be at all useful to you to try to do this for the n-fold or for the n case?